# dynamic scheduling by Julia

Tags: julia

I have a function for dynamic scheduling and I can use it for simple array and functions, for example I can use it for this code:

scheduling:

```
@everywhere function pmap(f,lst)
              np=nprocs()
              n=length(lst)
              results=Vector{Any}(n)
              i=1
              nextidx()=(idx=i;i+=1;idx)
              @sync begin
              for p=1:np
                  if p != myid() || np==1
                      @sync begin
                          while true
                              idx=nextidx()
                              if idx > n
                                  break
                              end
                              results[idx]= remotecall_fetch(f,p,lst[idx])
                          end
                      end
                  end
               end
              end
              results
              end
```

function:

```
@everywhere f(x)=x+1
f (generic function with 1 method)
```

array:

```
julia> arrays=SharedArray{Float64}(10)
10-element SharedArray{Float64,1}:
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0

julia> arrays=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]
1×10 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
```

result:

```
@everywhere function fsum(x)
       x+1
       end

pmap(fsum,arrays)
10-element Array{Any,1}:
  2
  3
  4
  5
  6
  7
  8
  9
 10
 11
```

my question is if I had this function and arrays, how should I use scheduling function?
function:

```
@everywhere f(x,y)=x.+y

julia> x=SharedArray{Float64}(2,2)
2×2 SharedArray{Float64,2}:
 0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0

julia> y=SharedArray{Float64}(2,2)
2×2 SharedArray{Float64,2}:
 0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0

julia> x=[1 2;3 4]
2×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2
 3  4

julia> y=[6 7;8 9]
2×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 6  7
 8  9
```

I wanted to call it by `pmap(f,x,y)` but I got this error:

```
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching pmap(::#f, ::Array{Int64,2}, ::Array{Int64,2})
You may have intended to import Base.pmap
Closest candidates are:
  pmap(::Any, ::Any) at REPL[1]:2
```

and I have another question too, How we can be sure our problem is running in different process? How we can monitor it?

Comment: Why not just use the built in `pmap`? It does dynamic scheduling like that, and it splats the arguments.

Comment: What do you mean? I have a function that it has several argument for example `x` and `y` and I want to call `pmap` function by two argument. for example as I told I wand to call it by  two matrices `x` and `y`

Comment: `pmap(f,zip(x,y))` makes a tuple of values. You may need to splat that.

Comment: when I use `pmap(f,zip(x,y))` I got an Error:pmap(f,zip(x,y))
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching getindex(::Base.Iterators.Zip2{Array{Int64,2},Array{Int64,2}}, ::Int64)
Stacktrace:
 [1] macro expansion at ./REPL[1]:16 [inlined]
 [2] macro expansion at ./task.jl:302 [inlined]
 [3] macro expansion at ./REPL[1]:10 [inlined]
 [4] macro expansion at ./task.jl:302 [inlined]
 [5] pmap(::Function, ::Base.Iterators.Zip2{Array{Int64,2},Array{Int64,2}}) at ./REPL[1]:7

Comment: Huh, what version of Julia are you on? I just tried `f(x,y) = x+y; pmap(f,1:5,6:10)` and it works. Have you restarted Julia? With the definition of `pmap` above you probably just overwrote it and have been using your own version which doesn't do the argument splatting. 

Note that for `zip` the full thing is `f(x,y) = x+y; g(x) = f(x...); pmap(g,collect(zip(1:5,6:10)))`. But again this should be unnecessary since `pmap(f,x,y)` works on a standard Julia installation with no overriding of `pmap`.

Comment: I work on julia 6

Comment: how do you do that? the function `pmap` has 2 argument but you call it by 3 arguments?

Comment: No, `pmap` splats the arguments after the `f`. `pmap(f,c...)` is the definition. So it takes however many arguments you want to give it, and spits it to `f`. Continue discussion in the [Julia Gitter](https://gitter.im/JuliaLang/julia).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pmap` splats the arguments, and so this works:

```
f(x,y) = x+y; pmap(f,1:5,6:10)
```

You probably re-defined `pmap` using what you have in the OP which doesn't splat the arguments and thus fails. You do not need to write your own here: if you just use the built-in version it will work.

Comment: but I got an Error,` julia> @everywhere f(x,y) = x+y; pmap(f,1:5,6:10)
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching pmap(::#f, ::UnitRange{Int64}, ::UnitRange{Int64})
You may have intended to import Base.pmap
Closest candidates are:
  pmap(::Any, ::Any) at REPL[10]:2`

Comment: Yes, because you redefined `pmap`. Don't do that. Please just restart Julia, and do not run the function you defined in the OP.

Comment: yes, it works but my question is how to use that function I wrote above`pmap` for dynamic scheduling? I want to parallel some program that has a lot of loops and I want to give tasks to each process by dynamic scheduling. so I saw that function in tutorial of julia and I want to use it for two matrices for example.

Comment: It does that automatically. `@parallel` is static scheduling. `pmap` is dynamic scheduling with batches (defaulting to `batch_size=1`). Try it on `sleep(rand())` and you'll see it re-distribute work as necessary.

Comment: Sorry I'm learning Julia recently, I don't know what is sleep() ? you mean pmap is parallel by default?  If x and y were matrices how can i use that?

Comment: Yes, `pmap` means parallel map. If you already added processes, then it will parallelize amongst them. You don't need to do anything to use it on matrices: `pmap(f,rand(4,4),rand(4,4))` works just fine. For extended discussion, please join the [Julia Gitter Chatroom](https://gitter.im/JuliaLang/julia) since StackOverflow comments are not for chatting.